# Function calling from another file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, function-call

I have a python file called `function_bucket.py` from which I need to `import` the `modalprem()` function into another file named `Array1.py` . Below I have mentioned the codes of both the functions but while calling the function "`No module named modalprem()`"error is showing to me!. Please help me about this error.

## Code for `function_bucket.py`

```
def main():
    def modalprem():
        return 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Code for `Array1.py`

```
import numpy as np
from Function_Bucket import modalprem()
modalprem()
def main():
    EA=50
    PT = 15
    PPT = 5
    AP = 50000
    Mode = 12
    PM = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    PY = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    AGE = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    PREM = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    i=1
    Modal_Premium = modalprem()
    print(Modal_Premium)
    if (Mode == 1):
        Modal_Premium = AP
    elif (Mode==2):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.5131
    elif (Mode==4):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.2605
    elif (Mode==12):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.0886
        
    while(i <180):
        PM[i] = i
        PY[i] = int( (i+11)/12)
        AGE[i] = EA + PY[i] -1
        if (PM[i]<=PPT*12 and ((PM[i]-1)%(12/Mode) == 0)):
            PREM[i] = Modal_Premium
        else:
            PREM[i] = 0
        i = i+1
    print(PM)
    print(PY)
    print(AGE)
    print(PREM)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks

Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

Comment: the function you define in function_bucket is `main`, not `modal_prem`. You need to define it outside of `main`. Also, don't call it when you import it, omit the `()` in the import statement

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the function_bucket file I need to define more than one no. of functions which I will be calling accordingly. Will the result be same in that case. @njk2

Comment: @lonerunner If I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes, you can define multiple functions.

Comment: you don't have to define "modal_prem" inside the main function in the "function_bucket.py" file. Just define it at top level and then import it in the other file.

Answer (score 0):

You Also Add Parenthesis in Import Function
I Think That's Why You Getting This Error

Try This in your **Array1.py**

```
import function_bucket

function_bucket.modalprem()
```

the function you define in `function_bucket` is `main`, not `modal_prem`. You need to define it outside of main

```
function_bucket.main()
```

You Also Add Parenthesis in Import Function

If It's Not Work It's Mean Your Are Not Sharing The right Python File Name

Comment: No module named "Function_Bucket" error is throwing

Comment: @lonerunner Make Sure The Your Second Python File In Same Directory Fore Example If Your `Array1.py` in Desktop Than You need to paste `function_bucket` in your desktop

Comment: @lonerunner Why You Are Not Calling Main Function?

Comment: @lonerunner Try To Execute Main Function Hope Fully It Will Work!

Comment: @lonerunner If My Answer Helpful to  You Please Accept My Answer by click check sign! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Code for function_bucket.py**

```
def main():
    def modalprem():
        return 1
    return modalprem
```

**Code for Array1.py**

```
import numpy as np
from function_bucket import main
modalprem=main()
def main():
    EA=50
    PT = 15
    PPT = 5
    AP = 50000
    Mode = 12
    PM = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    PY = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    AGE = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    PREM = np.arange(12*PT+1)
    i=1
    Modal_Premium = modalprem()
    print(Modal_Premium)
    if (Mode == 1):
        Modal_Premium = AP
    elif (Mode==2):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.5131
    elif (Mode==4):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.2605
    elif (Mode==12):
        Modal_Premium = AP *0.0886

    while(i <180):
        PM[i] = i
        PY[i] = int( (i+11)/12)
        AGE[i] = EA + PY[i] -1
        if (PM[i]<=PPT*12 and ((PM[i]-1)%(12/Mode) == 0)):
            PREM[i] = Modal_Premium
        else:
            PREM[i] = 0
        i = i+1
    print(PM)
    print(PY)
    print(AGE)
    print(PREM)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hopefully this would work as expected!

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function_bucket'

Comment: @lonerunner keep function_bucket name as file name either it is lower or upper it is case sensitive

Comment: Upper and Lower Cases has been taken care of, but still error

Comment: module 'Function_Bucket' has no attribute 'modalprem'

Comment: @lonerunner update Array1.py class as I have updated it import main then assign main() to modalprem object in Array1.py file

Comment: won't that be a problem to import main and then def main?`from function_bucket import main
def main():
`